# How to get navigation callbacks in customtabs

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

How to set the `void onNavigationEvent(int navigationEvent, Bundle extras)` for customtabs. My code looks something like

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    intentBuilder.setShowTitle(false);
    intentBuilder.setCloseButtonIcon(
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_back));
    intentBuilder.setStartAnimations(this, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    intentBuilder.setExitAnimations(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
            android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(
            this, intentBuilder.build(), Uri.parse(url), new WebviewFallback());
```

Answer (score 1):

`CustomTabsCallback` is added to the `CustomTabsClient` before you open the url.

You should not call static method of `CustomTabActivityHelper`, because the `CustomTabsSession` is created without `CustomTabsCallback`.

Instead you should change it to something like this:

`CustomTabsSession session = mClient.newSession(new CustomTabsCallback());`